# Excel: Get the days delayed from Start date to End date Using DatedIF?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a sample data here that I want to get the days delayed.

[image]

As you can see,

The data shows the records for those users who did not submit their project, users who submitted on-time, and users who actually dont submit their project.

Currently,

I have this formula

=DATEDIF(A2,B2,"d")

for the first row to calculate the days delayed of first row.

Can I add in this formula that detects if the user dont submit their project and the delayed days continues counting for day delayed? Like for example the data on row 4. The column submitted_project is blank means the user still dont submit their project the days delayed will start counting after the deadline.

Comment: By continuous counting, do you mean something like `=IF(ISBLANK(B2),TODAY(),B2)-A2`?

Comment: Yes sir continuous counting, to count the days delayed after the deadline up to current date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need DateDif for that. (By the way it's Date-Dif for "date difference", not Dated-If)

You can simply subtract the two dates from each other and format the result as a number.

DateDif expects the earlier date as the first parameter, that's why it errors when the first parameter is the later date, i.e. when the project was submitted before the due date.

But with simple subtraction like `=B2-A2` you can get the correct result. Better even, to check that both cells have dates before doing the calculation, to avoid misleading results, so

```
=if(count(A2:B2)=2,B2-A2,"")
```

[image]

Edit after comment:  Yes.

```
=IF(COUNT(A5:B5)=2,B5-A5,IF(B5="",TODAY()-A5))
```

Comment: Hello is it possible, continous counting of delayed days if the submitted column is blank?